# Using isinstance with StrEnum

Tags: python, enums

I'm using a similiar setup to the toy example provided below in a unit test where I'm trying to ensure the types in my `TypedDict` named `AnimalInfo` are correct.

```py
### types.py

from typing import TypedDict, Optional
from enum import StrEnum

class Animal(StrEnum):
     DOG = "DOG"
     CAT = "CAT"


class AnimalInfo(TypedDict):
     animal_type: Animal
     age: Optional[int]

### test_types.py

def test_types():
    d = {"animal_type": "CAT", "age": 2}
     assert all(
        [isinstance(d.get(k, None), AnimalInfo.__annotations__[k]) for k in d.keys()]
)
```

Unfortunately, the call to `isinstance` returns `False` for the `animal_type` key, assumedly as the value isn't explicitly of type `Animal` -- even when the particular string is a valid enum value of `Animal`. Is there a pythonic and simple way to get this to resolve to `True` without adding some conditionals that act on StrEnums? I feel like this should be default behaviour

Comment: The `StrEnum` type makes the equality check `"CAT" == Animal.CAT` true, but I don't think it has anything to say about `isinstance("CAT", Animal)`.

Answer (score 0):

`StrEnum`s are instances of type `str`, but `str`s are not instances of `StrEnum`s.